# Maximum length of MAIL FROM address

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server, email-bounces

When sending out emails with a `MAIL FROM` address > 81 characters I receive bounce messages from some MTAs:

> 501 Syntax error - Badly formatted address. (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

As soon as I change the `MAIL FROM` address to <= 81 characters, the MTA accepts my message.
I didn't find any limits in the RFC docs.

**Is this expected behaviour or is the recipients' MTA misconfigurated?**

Answer (score 6):

Accoding to the answers given at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386294/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address

The answer is 254 according to RFC 5321

So, those MTA are badly configured.

Comment: That's the length of a valid email address. Maybe it have something to do with the SMTP protocol or a different restriction though?

Comment: No, it has not. A SMTP server is magically required to actually acccept valid email addresses, or? How else would it work?